# Boundary Value Problem involving derivatives of order n>=2

Tags: boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

A Sturm-Liouville's problem is often presented with the following boundary values:
\begin{align}
\alpha_1\,y(a) + \beta_1\, y'(a) &= 0 \\
\alpha_2\,y(b) + \beta_2\, y'(b) &= 0
\end{align}

Would it have sense to use higher derivatives ? for instance:
\begin{align}
\alpha_1\,y(a) + \beta_1\, y'(a) + \gamma_1\, y''(a) &= 0 \\
\alpha_2\,y(b) + \beta_2\, y'(b) + \gamma_2\, y''(b) &= 0
\end{align}
and in such a case, should we expect to have a solution to the BVP ?

Comment: Your number of conditions needs to match the degree of the highest order derivative. Less, its underdetermined, more, its over determined.

Comment: Sturm-Liouville problems are second order. For a regular Sturm-Liouville problem, the second order derivative at a point is determined by the equation from the first derivative and the function value at that point. So you won't be able to impose a condition on $y''(a)$--that value would typically be determined from the equation and the values of $y(a)$ and $y'(a)$. Singular equations are a different story, but they still wouldn't fit into your proposed scheme.